# Equation for a glmmTMB model with exponential spatial covariance structure

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, spatial, glmmtmb

I have read description of the Spatial covariance structure with `glmmTMB`  on this link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html), in particular the spatial exponential structure.

I found it very useful and have applied the exponential structure to my analyses. Recently, I received a reviewers comment asking for the equation to be explicitly specified, not just a model formula. I looked at the page and although there is an equation the description is not very clear. Could someone please help me formulate the equation for the mixed model with exponential spatial covariance structure specified below (`pos` and `group` are computed exactly the same as in the page above).

`glmmTMB(y ~ x1+x2...+Xn + exp(pos + 0 | group), data=data)`

~Gitu